# Spring boot Hibernate Infinity fetch loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've made some research but without any specific answer.

I know how @JsonView... @JsonIgnore works... but my point here is about back end, the point of view from there. I'm working on spring boot and by default OSIV is enabled, so as far as I know, if I'm not wrong, if I make a call in database on an @Entity that has @ManyToMany association it will eagerly fetch everything.

Till there I have no issues, the problem is that the associated Collection also has Collections... And some services need to fetch them and others don't... Then I keep getting LazyInitializationException.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    private String categoryTitle;
    private String categoryDescription;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Category_Parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category_parent")
    )
    private Set<Category> parentCategory;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Category_Parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category_parent", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category")
    )
    private Set<Category> subCategory;
```

Then to prevent that error I used @Query like this

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    @Query("from Category c left join fetch c.subCategory left join fetch c.parentCategory")
    List<Category> getAllCategories();
}
```

Now I'm able to fetch it lazly... I used that @Query way because it is the only one I know to fetch the associated Collections... I heared about EntityGraph and Hibernate.initialize() but have no knowledge on how to proceed (would appreciate some link).

So, then I have Json exception because the json response is infinite. How can I avoid this new issue? Using DTO?

I appreciate.

**------ EDIT ------**

I've used @JsonView on the properties that I want to send as response, however if I use @JsonView over subCategory only, it works, but if I use on parentCategory I got the infinite loop once again... Can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

- You can add fetch = FetchType.LAZY to your @ManyToMany or @OneToMany annotation like this: @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY). More instruction is at https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: @TiagoVieira Can you add the full exception stacktrace?